# How to find proper LDFLAG of a library in a Makefile?

Tags: c++, ios, linker, makefile, clang

How does one know the name of the library when linking it with LDFLAGS in a Makefile?

For example:

libxml2.dylib is linked with -lxml2

libz.dylib which is actually named zlib is linked with -lz

Where are those flags specified? How does one look them up?

Comment: Remove the leading `lib` and the trailing `.dylib`, and prepend a leading `-l`.  What's so confusing/inconsistent about that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By convention, you remove the preceding 'lib' from the library filename.  For a library file called, 'libmyspecial_library.so', the corresponding flag is:

```
-lmyspecial_library
```

This is actually a convention with the gcc compiler.  See the [gcc man page](http://cf.ccmr.cornell.edu/cgi-bin/w3mman2html.cgi?gcc) for more info:

> ```
>    -llibrary
>       Use the library named library when linking.
>
>       The  linker searches a standard list of directories
>       for the library, which is  actually  a  file  named
>       `liblibrary.a'.   The linker then uses this file as
>       if it had been specified precisely by name....
> ```